# Canon LBP-810 printer not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have installed Windows 7 on my PC. My Canon LBP-810 printer is not working after the installation.

What should I do to run the printer on my PC?

Comment: Not working after the installation of Windows? Have you already downloaded the latest drivers or installed them using the driver CD that probably came with your printer? What steps did you already take? Do you get any error messages? What *exactly* is not working? Please [edit] your question and tell us a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This printer appears to be unsupported under Windows 7.  No Vista support either.

I ahave heard some HP universal printer drivers might work for this model.